# Database scheme for storing SNMP data

Tags: schema, snmp, database

I am trying to build a MYSQL DB for storing SNMP MIB information (a small subset of OIDs only).. Is there a DB schema that I may refer to?

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: What do you mean? A general purpose schema for SMI-like information? Or something specific to your use case? As ever, it's vanishingly unlikely we could give you a DB schema for a use case we know nothing about. Apply the normal routine of developing a schema for your data.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this of late. I would hazard a guess that you just map your MIB types to whatever fits your database e.g. `Unsigned32` in the MIB would be `UNSIGNED INT` in SQL. Then use the OID as your primary key.